# How to add spft record for an ip range?

Tags: linux, dns

I want to add spf record a range of 25 ip addresses.

For example : 192.168.1.225 to 192.168.1.250

How can I add this on spf record?  Would this be correct:

```
v=spf1 ip4:192.168.1.225-250/24 a mx ?all
```

Comment: this question should be asked on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

use CIDR notation "v=spf1 ip4:192.168.1.224/27 a mx ?all"